# Jquery Conflict Issue

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a Date picker in html Form with Jquery. Following is my code:

**Html head section code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-   
ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+12M +10D" });
});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
</script>
```

**Html Body Section Code:**

```
<p>Date From: <input type="text" id="datepicker" ></p>
<p>Date To: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" /></p>
```

Well, the form is working fine **BUT** I've another Jquery tab to the Footer of my site with following code **(Just giving jquery code)**

```
 <script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.tabify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-
8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu3').tabify();
            $('#menu2').tabify();
        });

        // ]]>
    </script>
```

**Question:** When I add this footer code then the Date Picker is not working. If i delete footer code then it's work fine. Why ? Is it conflicting.. ?

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors ?

Comment: You're including jQuery twice :x

Comment: @adeneo, I'm new in this area. I don't know what is console, can you tell me plz ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery 1.9 with jQuery UI 1.10.3. Those are conflicting version and don't work well with each other in my experience.

Comment: @billyonecan, How ? It's calling different jquery file, there is duplicated files.

Comment: @DyllenJamesOwens So what should i do now to working it fine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are loading two different jquery files..and i assume there version is different thus producing conflict...

either remove the jquery script in the footer..

remove this line

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

or use [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and instead of having three document.ready function ..you can add all the three javascript/jquery codes to one..

like

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+12M +10D" });
   $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
   $('#menu3,#menu2').tabify();

 });
</script>
```

Comment: where i put this "jquery.noConflict()" ?

Comment: @AlexMojum do you really need to have 2 different jQuery libraries? why not just use one?

Comment: i think removing `<script>` file in footer  should work.. you are already loading the latest stable version in header...

Comment: @AlexMojum bipen had the correct answer - There was just a little formatting issue that caused some of it to not appear

Comment: @bipen np :)  I thought it looked a little weird with just `remove this line`